# Can't Redirect to User Profile After Follow

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, relationships

I'm using the [acts_as_follower gem](https://github.com/tcocca/acts_as_follower). I'm also using Devise for my user model and instead of a format like users/:id, I've allowed users to have username URLs. I'm working on allowing users to follow each other, but after a user is followed, Rails fails to redirect to the user's profile. Here's my code.

User Controller

```
    def show
       @user = User.find_by_username(params[:id].downcase) 
    end

    def follow
       @user = User.find(params[:id])
       if current_user
         current_user.follow(@user)
         redirect_to @user.username
       else 
          flash[:error] = "You Must be logged in"
       end
    end
```

Here's the error that I'm getting in my server.

```
  ERROR URI::InvalidURIError: the scheme http does not accept registry part: localhost:3000alaxics (or bad hostname?)
```

Comment: can you try to add a `/` before the username?  like `redirect_to "/#{@user.username}"`

Answer (score 0):

You probably want something more like

```
redirect_to user_path(@user.username)
```

Or if you're intent on writing the path yourself, just `redirect_to "/users/#{@user.username}"`

Comment: Ahh. That makes sense. I don't know why I wasn't thinking when it came to this. Thanks, Chris.

Answer (score 0):

Remove the `.username`, just `redirect_to @user` should work as expected.

Whatever you pass to `redirect_to` has to be a valid path, and any string without at least a `/` in front won't be valid when appended to your root_url. This is exactly the error you're getting.

If you just redirect_to `@model`, that's a rails shortcut for `redirect_to model_path(@model)`, which is what you need.